# Table width and horizontal scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a product comparison website, so I've a [product compare page](http://telbat.nl/tablets-vergelijken/24-38-46-49-68-92-108-186-244-295/).

Sadly the column widths doesn't work well, the "header" on the left has to be 150px, all others 200px width (so 10x200+150=2150px). But when I lookup the table with Chrome Developer Tools it's 1170px width? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap where they have this (in bootstrap-responsive.css):

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 1170px;
}
```

How can I overrule this? So the width will be as set for the table: 2150px?

And my second question, [my rival has a fixed vertical header](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/compare/822/300706;304946;309996;314488;316453;317510;320048;320066;321626;322550/) and arrows on the left and right to scroll. I've searched a lot but I only find this for a horizontal table header.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: can you set overflow to on?

Comment: overflow-x that is, to scroll or auto

Comment: I've set overflow to auto on the table his parent; a div. That does the job to scroll horizontal, but that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and I hope you solved it already.

For your question actually you could go for well-made table plugin such as table sorter (https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter).  With proper options set you should be easily get what you need.

One good thing is that this tablesorter works well with BS2.x.  But if you already change to BS3, then it may look a bit strange, but still with good shape and function.

Comment: Could you add an example for a solution? Your answer is not very specifically dealing with tthe question asked...

Comment: For your question 1, the 1170px is set by BS2.x in bootstrap.responsive.css.  The media session fix the width to 1170px for all screens larger.  So to show any content with width 2150px, you need to write your own media session.

Comment: @Samoth, the tablesorter is easy to use. The docs in its website is clear and comes with lots of example, I believe Roy shall be able to get more help there.  Besides the rival link provided returns 404 so I'm not sure how exact Roy is looking for.